# Replace comma with dot in a GoogleMaps script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, number-formatting, google-distancematrix-api

I use a Google API (Distance Matrix) to calculate the distance between two points, but unfortunately for the values > 1000, I get the results in this form: 1,273.
Would it be possible to bring km with a dot instead of that comma?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qizaD.png)
Instead of 1,273 I want to have 1.273.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `'1,273'.replace(',','.')`

Comment: But that will work only for 1,273. What if the distance is 1,274?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear if the issue is that currently the comma is getting passed to the API and you want to pass a period instead, or that the API is returning a comma instead of a period when it gives the distance.

If you need to go comma -> period just use the replace method on a string: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

As for sending data back: worst case you reverse the transformation, but you could also just remove any non numeric characters and pass it back like that.

Comment: The comma is getting passed by the API.Thats the result (in km) from point A to point B. I want to get that value with dot instead of comma.

Comment: Then yes, just using string replacement will work fine.

Comment: Or better yet, some library that checks locale and formats the number properly, but I understand if that's over engineered for your use-case.

Comment: The value is calculated when I press a button, inside a < input >. Unfortunately I cant set to type="number" and step="any"

Comment: I don't know if you have a DOM library, but you could target the field with an OnChange handler of whatever flavor you prefer and then do the processing there. Is the API actually returning the distance as a string with the comma and not as just a number?

Comment: I'm really a noob to code...I don't really know what to say. I tried                 var str = document.getElementById("distanta").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace(/,/g, ".");
document.getElementById("distanta").innerHTML = res;      but this do nothing.

Comment: I would use JQuery or something, not native Javascript. The code you posted should work as far as I can tell, though you don't need /,/g, just do str.replace(',','.'). If it's not working maybe your selectors are bad. Fiddle around in your browser console and see what values look like.

Comment: I sent you an email with a proposal.

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming here that you are using the google maps api and on the link you can define the locale and region check this link

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&
language=es&
region=ES">
</script>
```

set language and region to your own and should print the number as you used to see them